# Bad version number in .class file - Mule, Soap and Restful

Tags: soap, mule

I have 2 web services, a SOAP and a Retsful service. I am hosting the Soap service via Mule.

As part of the Soap service, I am calling the Restful service, doing a GET with parameters.

Using SoapUI, I test the Soap service but am getting the following error in the Mule logs:

```
Message               : Component that caused exception is: SedaService{xxService}. Message payload is of type: Object[]
```

Type                  : org.mule.api.service.ServiceException

Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2

JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesource.org/docs/site/current2/apidocs/org/mule/api/service/ServiceException.html
Payload               : [Ljava.lang.Object;@12856b4

---

Exception stack is:

1. Bad version number in .class file (java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError)
   java.lang.ClassLoader:-2 (http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedClassVersionError.html)
2. Component that caused exception is: SedaService{xService}. Message payload is of type: Object[] (org.mule.api.service.ServiceException)
   org.mule.component.DefaultLifecycleAdapter:216 (http://www.mulesource.org/docs/site/current2/apidocs/org/mule/api/service/ServiceException.html)

---

Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

I am running Mule with JDK 5 and have compiled the Restful service with JDK 5 so it doesn't seem to be the compiler/running decrepency..

Do any of you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Full exception would help, but try with Java 6, most probably something was compiled with this JDK in your environment.